# set xaml code ItemsSource="{Binding}" with code behind

Tags: c#, datacontext, inotifypropertychanged, itemssource

I have the following property `Temp2`: (my UserControl implements INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
    ObservableCollection<Person> _Temp2;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Temp2
    {
        get
        { 
            return _Temp2; 
        }
        set
        {
            _Temp2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Temp2");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

---

I need to create a listview dynamically. I have the following listview in XAML:

```
<ListView 
     Name="listView1" 
     DataContext="{Binding Temp2}" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
 <ListView.View>
 .... etc
```

Now I am trying to create the same listview with c# as:

```
        ListView listView1 = new ListView();
        listView1.DataContext = Temp2;
        listView1.ItemsSource = Temp2; // new Binding(); // ????? how do I have to implement this line
        listView1.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
        //.. etc
```

when I populate the listview with C# the listview does not get populated. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to create a `Binding` object.

```
Binding b = new Binding( "Temp2" ) {
    Source = this
};
listView1.SetBinding( ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, b );
```

The argument passed to the constructor is the `Path` that you're used to from XAML bindings.

You can leave out the `Path` and `Source` if you set the `DataContext` to `Temp2` as you do above, but I personally think it's preferable to bind to a ViewModel (or other data source) and use a `Path` than to directly bind to a class member.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set some properties of the Binding instance. In your case it will probably be something like...

```
listView1.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = Temp2 });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
listView1.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
```